# react-router transitionTo() how to not refresh

Tags: react-router

I'm using "react-router": "0.13.2"

I'm try to append query string to my page using the react router transitionTo, like the following

```
router.transitionTo("home", {}, {"test":"test"});
```

It appends ?test=test as expected, but my page is also get refreshed.

**Question:** I wonder if there is anyway that adding a query string to the url and **NO** refresh happen?

Or should I not use **transitionTo()**  ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we're supposed to use the Navigation mixin rather than this.context.router. But the API is the same.

When this error happened to me I was clicking on an anchor tag and not handling the event so it naturally did the transition. I'd make sure you aren't using an  tag.